# Make a np array with one str column and one int column

Tags: python, numpy

I like to make a simple 2D array that stores int in one column str in another column. I tried to make an int array first and then, change one column to str. But it did not work:

```
order= np.ones((300,2), dtype=int)
order[:,0]=order[:,0].astype(str)
```

I look for a simple way, not merging (e.g., numpy.concatenate)

Comment: you need `pandas`

Comment: Of course it didn't work!  I'm afraid you skipped over the intro chapters of the numpy documentation.  But feel free to show us an example from the documentation, or other SO, of the kind of array that you expect.

Comment: @hpaulj see the answer down below!!

Comment: Beware though that an object array is a lot like a list, with just a superficial multidimensional quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want and array with ones like string and ones like number:

```
order= np.ones((300,2), dtype=object)
order[:,0]="1"
order
```

Is it that you want?